# How to create a PDF menu

Tags: pdf

How can I create a menu in a PDF file, similar to this one:

http://www.pwc.com/us/en/10minutes/assets/10minutes-on-the-cloud.pdf

The menu appears when you hover over the top of the page. It works both inside the browser (using Acrobat Reader) and using a different PDF reader (I tested with Foxit Reader).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is done with layers, with mouse events controlling layer visibility and colors. The menu bar is likely on a master page, so is potentially visible on all pages. The author used InDesign CS4, which looks to be available on a trial download basis.

[This page](http://layersmagazine.com/acrobat-9-adding-layers-to-pdf-documents.html) describes adding layers in Acrobat 9, and [this page](http://www.adobe.com/designcenter/video_workshop/?id=vid0069) talks about master pages and layers in InDesign. I did not find an example that specifically created a menu like the one in your pdf.

Answer (score 1):

There is a giant invisible button there, most likely a rectangle with its opacity set to zero.
The invisible button has been set to show a group of other buttons on rollover and hide them on rollout.

You can easily figure it out inside InDesign.

Answer (score 0):

@W_Whalley: No, it is not done with layers.

It's just...

- ... set to open in fullscreen mode (which hides normal PDF reader menues, page info display and buttons),
- ... and it uses simple mouse clicks on hyperlinks which take you to the linked page.

Master page used: no; InDesign used to create the PDF: yes.